# Is it reasonable to use tellp and seekp to set block size after logging into file?

Tags: c++, file

For a data logging application, I will have to write some blocks of (previously) unknown size into a file. To faciliate reading, I'd like to add information about the block size. The data can be large compared to the size of the RAM, therefore a solution with a buffer in RAM is no good idea.

My plan is to reserve an `int` at the beginning of the block, store its position with `tellp`, then write the block and count its size and then return to the position of the length info and write the actual size:

```
  // 1. some stuff was written to the file here
  // 2. reserve space for block length information and store its position:
  long len = 0;
  off_t pos = outfile.tellp(); // get position where len will be stored
  outfile.write(&len, sizeof(long)); // write a dummy len

  // 3. a block of previously unknown length is written to the file here

  // 4. return to the position of the block length and write the actual size:
  outfile.seekp (pos);
  outfile.write (&len,sizeof(long));
```

Is that a reasonable way to achieve what I want or are there significant drawbacks/problems/pitfalls?

Comment: Side note: be careful with your data sizes. `tellp()` returns `stream::off_type` (usually `off_t`) which isn't necessarily a `long`. Also `sizeof(int) != 4` quite often, now. Also: byte order when writing the value directly.

Comment: Aside from these serialization problems, don´t use a 4 byte integer for that (but 8). Else, the max size of your data is 4GB.

Comment: Do you mean a sequence of blocks, and each block begins with the block length? The question is very confusing to me.

Comment: Ok, updated that with `int` types. I'm also working on the byte order issue...

Comment: If the blocks are large, why not put them in separate files?

Comment: About your edit: Careful about such changes. Don´t change `int` to `long` without changing the `sizeof` things (etc.) too (ok, corrected now). And instead of variable sized types, there is eg. `uint64_t`

Comment: And worth to mention:  the file must be opened as `ios::binary`

Comment: @Michael - use a fixed-width unsigned integer type such as `uint64_t` as deviantfan already mentioned, but write it to the file using `htonll()` to write a defined byte order (big-endian in this example, but any defined order would work).  Then use `ntohll()` when reading the length.

Comment: Thank's for the additional hints. I'm still looking for a short but "complete" example about best practices for reading/writing binary files. Unfortunately, a request for such an example on SO got closed, because "opinion based". And I also did not find a real good example in the internet by now. So it would be greatly appreciated if someone would know a link to a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serialisation method isn't quite up to scratch but, yes, **the basic premise is sound**.

I take an approach much like this, returning to the beginning of a large binary log file as it's being generated, to update an "index" block found at the start of the file that helps with later traversal through the generated data.

Don't forget the following:

- open the file in binary mode to avoid e.g. serialised `10` becoming something else;
- document/constrain the value's format (at least, endianness);
- pick a fixed-width integer type, like `uint64_t`.

Of course, if there's any way you can work more on predicting the block size in advance then you can avoid all the seeking around. :)